# How to document which test(s) are applicable for a function in Python?

Tags: python, testing, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a function in Python. I would like to document the location of one or more tests for this function - maybe in docstrings, maybe in comments, maybe somewhere in function body or above it... actually, any place close to function body will do.

What I want is to quickly find which test(s) were written for this specific function.

I do have a naming convention for tests in my project but for some cases it quickly becomes insufficient.

Also, as I am using an IDE for this project, I would like it to understand those references to test function names, so I could easily control-click to a test function location.

I have looked through Sphinx documentation, but didn't found any tags like `:test:` or something like that. I could document the location using `:py:func:` or `:y:class:` but it doesn't look like my IDE of choice (PyCharm) understand those cross-references - if I have a line like `:param foo:`, it looks like I can reference classes using `:py:class:`.

Are there any reasonable, standardized solutions for this little problem of mine? Except creating a custom tag for Sphinx, that's for sure - this will work, but chances are PyCharm won't understand it. Did you have this problem too? What worked for you?

**Edit**: I use `pytest`, if this matters.

Comment: Do you have any specific testing framework in mind?

Comment: Although documenting tests is sadly neglected, the convention is the same as that for Python projects, specifically use docstrings. From there, in PyCharm, select the root of your tests directory, and find all instances of your function therein.

Comment: @bad_coder I use pytest. Question updated.

Comment: @StevePiercy I do have a convention for my tests. ``test_ClassName_functionName_some_extra_stuff`` . Unfortunately, there is no easy option to jump to the test function in my IDE. Also, such convention doesn't satisfy all the possible cases... which aren't even corner-cases, mind that.

Comment: Probably not a straight, satisfying answer, but: don't IDEs show you the references to where a specific function is used, including the tests? So you would (only) need to scroll through the list of references to find the tests?

Comment: Your question is two-fold, the main thing is: "how do I conveniently jump to test definitions right clicking in the source files?" Well, you aren't supposed to pollute the docstring with cross-references to the tests. Because except the devs/contributors, users of a library aren't interested in the tests, they're interested only in the functionality. So you'd divide your documentation (a separate for the tests, and possibly with a separate index). But finding tests is best done using pytest on cmd-line (or "find-usages" in IDE), otherwise you're depending on the documentation which may outdate

Comment: So, I suppose an answer to your question would go along the lines of methodically exploring these possibilities trying to find something close to optimal. But there are several ways of doing this, I don't think there's 1 clear way because each alternative has its own drawbacks.

Comment: @dotz you do not have to type the entire name. In the Project window, type "clafunsome", and PyCharm should highlight the test you seek or use down-arrow to go to the next instance.